# Perl:Issue passing self

Tags: perl

I'm having an issue with a recent code review. I've been advised to change the following function call:

```
 storeShmcoreservJobsLogs(
    $self->{'shmJobDetails'},
    $self->{'nhcJobDetails'},
    $self->{'cppDetails'},
    $self->{'siteId'},
    $neTypesIdMap,
    $dbh
);
```

To only use two arguments, being `$self` and `$dbh`. So I have coded as follows

```
storeShmcoreservJobsLogs($self, $dbh);
```

And the function signature as follows:

```
sub storeShmcoreservJobsLogs($$) {
  my($self, $dbh) = @_;

  if ( $#{$self->$shmJobDetails} > -1 ) {
```

The `if` statement unfortunately throws an error with the value of `$shmJobDetails` when I test the change

> Global symbol "$shmJobDetails" requires explicit package name at /data/ddp/current/analysis/TOR/elasticsearch/handlers/misc/Shm.pm line 148.

So I must have misinterpreted the instruction. Is anything obvious wrong?

Comment: Your variable `$self->{'shmJobDetails'}` will have the same name instead any function where you passed `$self` so why do you rewrite the variable name? The compiler is telling you that you are using a variable `$shmJobDetails` which is never defined anywhere in your code, which is true, as this is not a variable, you just have `shmJobDetails` being one of the key inside the `$self` hash reference. Also `$self` smells about object orientation, so have a look at that.

Comment: Is that all they told you in your code review? You're missing a good deal of stuff.

Comment: Note: `sub func(...) {  }` is _not a signature_, as the term is understood in other languages.  These are _prototypes_ and they are subtly and very seriously different.  Besides, they (prototypes) don't do anything in a class, what this appears to be related to, so there are far bigger questions.

Comment: Tip: `if ( $#{ $self->{'shmJobDetails'} } > -1 )` can also be written as `if ( @{ $self->{shmJobDetails} } )`

Answer (score 1):

There's no variable `$shmJobDetails` so you get the compilation error. Do the same thing that you were doing before:

```
sub storeShmcoreservJobsLogs {
    my($self,$dbh)=@_;

    if ( $#{ $self->{'shmJobDetails'} } > -1 ) {
```

Now you're passing the complete object and the subroutine can use any part of the object it needs.

You might want to make some object methods to answer the questions you'll ask it instead of accessing its internals. That method can do all the work to figure out true or false:

```
sub storeShmcoreservJobsLogs {
    my($self,$dbh)=@_;

    if ( $self->has_jobs ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of a lexical variable called `$self` implies that you're using object-oriented methods, but your code is far from being object-oriented

Are you sure that you understand the points being made in the code review? It's looking like you're writing a *method*, and the fields should be extracted from the hash *within the method*

The method definition should be more like this

```
sub store_shmcoreserv_jobs_logs {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($id_map, $dbh) = @_;

    my @fields = @{$self}{qw/ shmJobDetails nhcJobDetails cppDetails siteId /};

    ...
```

while the call should look like this

```
$self->storeShmcoreservJobsLogs($neTypesIdMap, $dbh)
```

All of this is essential to Perl object-oriented programming. You should study [`perlobj`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) together with the rest of the [Perl language reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/index-language.html)